# How can I access a property from an ActionFilterAttribute in my ApiController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a custom `ActionFilterAttribute`. For the sake of this question let's assume it's as follows:

```
public class CustomActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public bool success { get; private set };

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        //Do something and set success
        success = DoSomething(actionContext);
    }
}
```

My controller is then decorated with `CustomActionFilter`. What I am looking for is a way (in my controller method) to do something like:

```
[CustomActionFilter]
public class MyController : ApiController {
    public ActionResult MyAction() {
        //How do I get the 'success' from my attribute?
    }
}
```

If there is a more accepted way of doing this please let me know.

Comment: duplicate of [How do you Read the value of an attribute in a Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493143/how-do-you-read-the-value-of-an-attribute-in-a-method)

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for me because my attribute is not on the action but on the controller.

Comment: Would this one work for you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime

Comment: I suppose that could possibly work but I was able to solve it in my answer below before I saw your response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered I could do the following to satisfy my problem:

```
[CustomActionFilter]
public class MyController : ApiController {
    public ActionResult MyAction() {
        var myAttribute = ControllerContext
                          .ControllerDescriptor
                          .GetCustomAttributes<CustomActionFilter>()
                          .Single();
        var success = myAttribute.success;
    }
}
```