# How to get TestCategory for a Testcase using C#, Visual Studio MS Test

Tags: c#, mstest, categories, testcaseattribute

I am looking to find Test Category of a testcase at runtime using c#. I am using MSTEST, TestContext does not have any information related to TestCategory, I want to capture/log TestCategory information.   In my case I have multiple TestCATEGORIES assigned to a testcase.. Example

BaseTest will have  Initialization and CleanUp methods..

```
[TestClass]
    public class CustomerTest : BaseTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("Smoke")]
        [TestCategory("regression")]
        public void Login()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the attributes inside a test method like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Smoke")]
[TestCategory("regression")]
public void Login()
{
    var method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
    foreach(var attribute in (IEnumerable<TestCategoryAttribute>)method
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestCategoryAttribute), true))
    {
        foreach(var category in attribute.TestCategories)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(category);
        }
    }
    var categories = attribute.TestCategories;  
}
```

If you want to get the categories at another place than inside the test method you can use

```
var method = typeof(TheTestClass).GetMethod("Login");
```

to get the method base and get the attributes as described above.

Source: [Read the value of an attribute of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493143/how-do-you-read-the-value-of-an-attribute-in-a-method)

Comment: thanks for showing me the way how to do it & providing the source.

Comment: In my case for the test I have three categories, when I execute the test -- I am logging the test category. From VSConsole when I am executing based on TestCaseFilter,  but it's logging three categories. Can I explicitly set something which tells tetscase is set to run under this category -- TestCaseFilter

Comment: I don't know. I suggest you post a new question for that.