# Is there a way to read test attribute value like [Owner="Tester"] with c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I want to know if there is a way to read test attribute value?
For example

```
[TestMethod , TestCategory ("Smoke Test"), Priority (1), Owner ("Tester")]
```

if there is way to get the value of test owner attribute as string using c#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read the value of an attribute of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493143/read-the-value-of-an-attribute-of-a-method)

Comment: I have 1100+ test methods in different classes with different owner names assigned to them. Need some generic method to get owner attribute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Helper
    {
        public static TValue GetOwnerAttributeValue<TValue>(MethodBase method, Func<OwnerAttribute, TValue> valueSelector) 
        {
           return method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OwnerAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() is OwnerAttribute attr ? valueSelector(attr) : default(TValue);
        }

    }
```

Called this way

```
var testMethod = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1)
            .GetMethod();
        var testAuthor = Helper.GetOwnerAttributeValue(testMethod, x => x.Owner);
```

Comment: Better way to call it                                                                                                                  var owner = Helper.GetOwnerAttributeValue(GetType().GetMethod(TestName), x => x.Owner);

Answer (score 1):

I think [TestContext](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext) could help you.

```
var category = (string) TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Category");
```

---

I am speaking about runtime, otherwise, you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493143/read-the-value-of-an-attribute-of-a-method)(tnx to [Mark Benningfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600924/is-there-a-way-to-read-test-attribute-value-like-owner-tester-with-c-sharp#comment97897797_55600924))

Comment: thank you for help, i used Mikael Engver solution  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493143/read-the-value-of-an-attribute-of-a-method)